# Python: merge large datasets and how to work with large data (500 Gb)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, large-data

I have some large csv files which I need to merge them together. each file is about 5gb and my RAM is only 8gb. I use the following code to read some csv files into dataframes and merge them on columns `fund_ticker` `ticker` and `date`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Read in data, ignore column "version"
table1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\data\data1.csv', usecols=lambda col: col not in ["Version"])
table2 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\data\data2.csv', usecols=lambda col: col not in ["Version"])
weight = pd.read_csv(r'C:\data\data3.csv', usecols=lambda col: col not in ["Version"])

print("Finish reading")

# merge datasets
merged = data1.merge(data2, on=['fund_ticker', 'TICKER', 'Date']).merge(data3, on=['fund_ticker', 'TICKER', 'Date'])
```

Unfortunately, I got the following error:

```
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 105. MiB for an array with shape (27632931,) and data type object
```

After searching on the internet, I think the issue is that the data is larger than my RAM. To overcome this issue, I am thinking about using some database such as SQL or parquet files. My question is which is the most efficient ways to work with large datasets? My data is financial data and could go up to 500 Gb or 1 Tb. Some direction to how to set up would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You'll need something other than Pandas. Pandas will load the data to memory no matter what. If you'd be doing a merge/join operation, you might want to consider loading the data to an SQL database and have it do it. Another option is to simply write this code in a streaming manner by hand.

Comment: @AKX Thanks, does SQL depends on RAM?

Comment: SQL database systems will perform better if there's more RAM, but generally aren't hard-dependent on it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options discussed on the ['Scaling to large datasets' page of the pandas User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/scale.html)

The easiest drop-in replacement here would be to use [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html)

It uses a subset of the pandas api, so that should be familiar, and it allows working with dataframes that are larger than the memory by only working on chunks at a time.

However, that merge is likely to still be quite slow. (It would help some to set the 'fund_ticker', 'TICKER', and 'Date' columns as the index of each dataframe first.